# ICS Emulator will not create Calendar Account

Tags: android, calendar, emulation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, account

Please help.  I absolutely need to be able to test the Calendar.contract provider in my app using the SDK emulator.  Purchasing a $400 hardware device just to test is not a real option.

I have seen the posts that remind us that we need to target the Google API platform, which we have done.  Next, I have seen a work around where it is suggested that we create a google account as an exchange account by specifying the m.google.com server and clicking "Accept all SSL".  Unfortunately, that generates the error that:

***You have typed an incorrect server address or the server requires a protocol version that Email doesn't support.***

We created a basic Google account.  However, the emulator still says we must create at least one calendar account and forces us into creating the Echange Account.  According to the emulator, the account we did create as a Google account has no calendars associated with it, even though I can go to Google Calendar, access that account, and add items to a calendar.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks,

Comment: Technically, since the Nexus 7 just started shipping -- that price is now $199. But if I were you, I'd go to a user group of Android developers (assuming there is one near you) and ask to borrow one of their devices during the meeting. Few developers will allow you to borrow their device overnight, but most should allow you to borrow one during the duration of a meeting for testing purposes.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, in my experience testing and debugging is not something that can be accomplished with just an hour or two on a borrowed phone.  If there has been a change in the emulator so that the old work around doesn't work anymore, that seems like a serious problem for the Android developer community.  Perhaps someone has already discovered a new workaround?

Comment: With ICS (and up) having a cumulative marketshare of only 11% among Android devices, I don't expect too many Android developers without ICS devices to even target that api level yet. In other words, I wouldn't hold my breath if I were you. The most you can do is finding the bug on the developer tools bug tracker and starring the issue so that you get notified whenever there is a fix/workaround for it.

Comment: I'm facing same problem, did you find the solution?

Comment: No, sadly I still have no answer.  I am hoping someone from the actual Android dev team can jump in with a solution.